# Winforms delete entireline if first value in delimited text is duplicated

Tags: c#

Does anyone have any sample code of how to do this?

From:

> Janella,541,Room B
>
> **Harvey**,456,Room A
>
> Joshua,128,Room B
>
> **Harvey**,412,Room A
>
> Kaye,854,Room B
>
> **Amy**,465,Room B
>
> **Amy**,741,Room B

To

> Janella,541,Room B
>
> **Harvey**,456,Room A
>
> Joshua,128,Room B
>
> Kaye,854,Room B
>
> **Amy**,465,Room B

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");

File.WriteAllLines("filename.txt", lines.Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work like that. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? It is not even clear what you try to do. Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: I think he wants to remove duplicate rows. But from where?? (is it from database?)

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean. :)
From text file.

Comment: without testing (and barely any research effort) - `lines.GroupBy(ln => ln.Split(",").First()).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToArray()` - I do kind of think your just masking another problem however of actually allowing people to be assigned two rooms in the first place

Comment: I got an error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'
& The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: change `","` to `new char[]{','}`

Comment: No worries, I added it as an answer incase it helps other users in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
lines.GroupBy(ln => ln.Split(new char[]{','}).First())
     .Select(grp => grp.First()).ToArray()
```

Although, I do believe you are covering a bigger problem by allowing a person to be assigned two rooms.